# Should I report driving tickets on my international driving permit to insurance companies

Tags: united-states, insurance

I have an international driving permit I got from India for driving into United States. I have 2 tickets on it in US. Now that I have got my own driving permit in US, should I report to insurance companies about driving tickets I have from IDP or should I just enter my new License details and mark "NO" for previous driving tickets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are expected report. The question is not whether you got tickets when you had that specific license in the pocket, but whether you got tickets at all.

Comment: Do they have a way to detect if I ever got ticket?

Comment: That's an entirely different issue. They may, especially if the name and the address you have the officer matches the name and the address on the local license.